# Keep Edge running while Windows Server 2019 remote session is locked

Tags: microsoft-edge, servicenow, windows-server-2019

I want to execute [ServiceNow Automated Tests](https://www.servicenow.com/products/automated-testing-framework.html), which requires a browser session to be connected to the instance.
As our tests run for about 15 hours, I've ordered a virtual Windows Server 2019 running a Microsoft Edge browser.
I noticed that the tests stopped being executed after the screen was locked.

How can I force Microsoft Edge to continue to run whilst the screen is locked?

Comment: Does it happen for other browsers, too? Does it have any error message?

Comment: Hi @KendrickLi, yes it happens with FireFox as well. The tests just time-out after 600 seconds - beside the timeout no error message.